# Insert in multiple rows values of select of same name PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table "items" and I would like to insert different values in different rows from different "select" with same name. Below the code:

```
try
        {
    $item_description = (is_array($_POST['item_description'])) ? $_POST['item_description'] : [];
    $item_description_string = explode(',', $item_description);
    $stmt2 = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO items (item_description) VALUES (:item_description)') ;
    $stmt2->bindValue(':item_description', $item_description_string);
    if ($stmt2->execute());
              
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>

<select name="item_description[]" class="activities">
<option value="Bartholomew Island">Bartholomew Island</option>
</select>

<select name="item_description[]" class="activities">
<option value="North Seymour Island">North Seymour Island</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What seems to be the trouble?

Comment: `explode` creates an array from a string, you are looking for `implode` which creates a string from an array.

Comment: @Second2None what is the use for implode here?

Comment: @Byron9212 Simple iterate over $_POST['item_description'] array with foreach

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah you are correct, it's got no purpose. I got a little ahead of myself haha.

Comment: @showdev why do you think it's not the same question? A form control with the same name that brings an array to PHP. A database table into which the selected values go. What debugging details do you need for a simple question of inserting several values into a database?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wasn't clear on the crux of the issue. I was looking more for "desired behavior" and "a specific problem or error". Nothing personal, just weird to be listed on a closure I didn't vote for.

Comment: @showdev yes, it's strange for me too. that's how this engine works for some reason. the desired behavior is clear though, "insert different values in different rows", which basically involves a loop, which is lacking in the code. Once added, it resolves the issue

Comment: Thank you all, I managed to resolve the issue :) now I am looking to update the select